# Canvas - game loading for slow internet

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have problem with canvas game loading.

I have plenty of images, one sound effect and background music. On PC everything will load very nice. The problem is with mobile phone, where I have slow internet. The images loads but the sound and background music are downloading after the game starts.

**Code example:**

```
main = getElementById('wrapp');
bg = new Image();
bg.src = 'bg.png';

msound = new Audio('main.wav');
msound.volume = .05;
msound.load();
msound.loop = true;
msound.play();

sound = new Audio('jump.wav');
sound.volume = .20;
sound.load(); 

main.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
     sound.play();
}

//some game functions

function Update() {
    //some functions 
}

function Start() {
    Update();
    requestAnimFrame(Start);
}
```

How to make the page load everything and then run the game? For example: there could be an information 'Please Wait..." and after the images and sounds will load, the canvas will show up.

Comment: wav files are very big. Either compress them, or don't load them at all. There's no reason to make somebody have to load those just to play on a mobile device.

Comment: Not useful answear. I still dont know how to load files before game starts.

Comment: You should be listening for events to tell you when your media has been loaded, and start the main game loop only when everything has finished loading. Use `'load'` for `Image` objects and `'canplaythrough'` for `Audio` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the fast dirty solution:

```
mainsound.addEventListener("canplay", function()
{
   mainsound.play();
   Start();
});
```

However a proper solution should involve:

1. Designing a class, responsible for the loading of media
2. Waiting for all media to be loaded. (you can use a combination of "$(window).load()" and the "oncanplay" event. If you are not into jQuery, you can look in google for stuff like [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/preloadimagesplus.shtml)
3. Starting the game from there